# Auto properties creation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, python-decorators

I have a class which has a many properties returning a list of values.

I want to create a decorator to the property, that will automatically create two more properties in the class with the same logic - the mean and the std of the values.

Currently the class looks like:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        # init function

    def calc_mean(self):
        # mean calculation implementation

    def calc_std(self):
        # std calculation implementation

    @property
    def list_a(self) -> list[float]:
        return self._list_a

    @property
    def list_a_mean(self) -> float:
        return self.calc_mean(self.list_a)

    @property
    def list_a_std(self) -> float:
        return self.calc_std(self.list_a)

    @property
    def list_b(self) -> list[float]:
        return self._list_b

    @property
    def list_b_mean(self) -> float:
        return self.calc_mean(self.list_b)

    @property
    def list_b_std(self) -> float:
        return self.calc_std(self.list_b)

    # more lists ...
```

And I want it to look like:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        # init function

    def calc_mean(self):
        # mean calculation implementation

    def calc_std(self):
        # std calculation implementation

    @stat_property
    def list_a(self) -> list[float]:
        return self._list_a

    @stat_property
    def list_b(self) -> list[float]:
        return self._list_b

    # more lists ...
```

and still to have the properties `list_a_mean`, `list_a_std`, etc.

Comment: That seems a very clumsy approach. Wouldn't it be better to instantiate multiple instances of Data where each instance manages a particular list?

Comment: Each list is a view of a greater list saved in the class, calculated dynamically, so creating many classes managing the lists might be less efficient memory-wise

Comment: Can you return a `dict` to manage the statistics? something like `return dict(mean=self._compute_mean(self._list_a), std=self._compute_std(self._list_a), ...)`

Comment: This is possible, but vary similar to @DarkKnight's approach of creating a class instance for each list

Comment: Why a method is not allowed?

Comment: @AndreaDiIura I have something like 50 lists, and I don't want my class to have 150 methods

Comment: you can create a single method with a parameter `def get_mean(name: str): return self._compute_mean(getattr(self, "_list_{}".format(name))`